# GIT - branches, what is branch?

Tags: git, branch

I am new to GIT. 
I want to create a new branch: I have 3 files inside that repository.

If I create a new branch, do I have to copy that files; Or are they copied automatically if I create a new branch?

When I want work on the branch, do I have to switch to that branch inside GIT, before I start to work (opening that files)?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Git does all the file system modifications for you.

Comment: Please google such simple well-documented questions. SOF is not intended to cover these sort of things

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a new branch

```
# checkout new branch based upon the current branch 
git checkout -b <new branch name>
```

---

> If I create a new branch, do I have to copy that files; Or are they copied automatically if I create a new branch?

The new branch is a **FULL** copy to the current branch.
In order to understand why you need to know what is branch in git.

---

#### What is branch in GIT?

A branch in Git is simply a **lightweight movable** pointer to commit.
[Here](https://backlogtool.com/git-guide/en/stepup/stepup1_1.html) is a very short and simple post about it

#### In other words:

Branch in git is simply a pointer to a commit.
As you can see in the image below (taken from the post mentioned above), all the branches are pointing to commit B + the delta which was added to them.

When you create branch git creates a file and writing the commit id to this file.

[image]

> When I want work on the branch, do I have to switch to that branch inside GIT, before I start to work (opening that files)?

This is what's the `checkout -b` does - switch you to the new branch
[image]