# Can't update project to a specific branch

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

So this is likely a software problem, but I think its just me misunderstanding things so I'm asking here.

I'm doing a project with multiple people for the first time and doing a github project.

As I'm understanding it, branches are just different versions, so I wanted to do a development branch and use the master branch for the finished product.

Now I can't figure why I can't update my workspace with the content of the branch. For testing I just made two different readmes in each branch. Works fine, I can just pull to get the files from the master branch.

I did all of that using the inbuilt VCS tools in PhpStorm.

So now I created the new branch (development) locally, fetched everything from the remote repo and then set up the local branch to track the remote branch with

```
git branch --track development origin/development
```

If I understood everything correctly, I should now be able to pull everything from the branch, right? Keep in mind I still have the master readme in my workspace, but when I pull or try to commit changes it tells me there are no changes every time, although the readmes are clearly different.

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all start by reading about [Git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) which will suit your need to develop and use master for production.

To understand more about branches read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921623/git-branches-what-is-branch):

---

> Now I can't figure why I can't update my workspace with the content of the branch

You will need to merge your branch (the one which you developed on) into the current branch.

```
git pull <my other branch>
```

This will "update" your current branch with the content of the second branch.

---

> ... If I understood everything correctly, I should now be able to pull everything from the branch, right?

The simple answer is yes. but it would be better if you continue developing on a separate branch and once in a while pull the content of the development branch into your current branch instead of changing it tracking branch.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to do! I don't want to pull my dev branch into the master one, I wan't to pull the files of the dev branch into my workspace.

Comment: Anyway, I'll try to use the model you linked, thanks

Comment: Rad about it. its a n excellent model which is similar to you r needs.