# There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with

Tags: git

So I created a branch using Jira and I checked out that branch on my local system. Now I'm trying to do a git pull on my local system but I'm getting this message

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature/branch-name                                                                                                                                        mark-violation
```

What do I need to do? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32056324/3001761) link, but it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does git remote mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889346/what-does-git-remote-mean)

Comment: If the branch was created through jira, then you need to run `git fetch` so you are able to see it, then you can check it out: `git checkout name-of-the-branch`. Given that the branch does not exist locally, git will check if there's a remote branch with that name. If there's only one remote branch with that name, it will create it locally and associate it with the remote branch.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4693588/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34921623/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32056324/3001761

Comment: @eftshift0 I didn't do ```git fetch``` but I did  ```git checkout -b <branch-name>```. Would that work. If not, what do I do now?

Comment: Oh... ok... I quite didn't get the whole situation. What you want to _pull_ is whatever changes are done on the base branch? (say, `main` or `master`)

Comment: @eftshift0 but I'm getting that message when I do a ```git pull```

Comment: Well.... sure... if you created the branch with `checkout -b` then it has no upstream branch set. You can specify from which branch to pull changes with `git pull the-remote the-upstream-branch` (replace the two relevant values). That is, a only once thing. If you want to fix the upstream branch you can set it like this: `git branch --set-upstream the-remote/the-upstream-branch`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two Gits in this story. Let's call them Jira's Git and your local Git.

- When you created a branch on Jira's Git, you did just that: created a branch on Jira's Git.
- When you said `git checkout -b branch-name` on your local Git, you created a branch on your local Git.

Those two branches have no relationship to one another at all. They may happen to have the same name, but that's just a coincidence; they know nothing of one another.

You have not even told us if there is any relationship between your local Git and Jira's Git in the first place. But if there is — if you created the local Git by cloning Jira's Git, or if you have attached Jira's Git to your local Git as a remote — then the correct procedure was to `git fetch` in order to create remote-tracking branches in your local Git that *are* tied to Jira's Git. You could then have checked one of those out as a local branch.

If it's too late for that because you've created a local branch already, you can tie it to the remote-tracking branch after `git fetch` by saying

```
git branch -u origin/branchname branchname
```

The `-u` means "set-upstream" and ties the local branch, `branchname`, to the remote-tracking branch, `origin/branchname` (assuming that `origin` is the local name of the remote that designates Jira's Git). Please note that this is *exactly* what Git already told you to do when it said you should say

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature/branch-name
```

You could have just done that and you'd be home by now.

---

Note that there are actually *three* branches in this story: the branch on Jira Git, the remote-tracking branch in your local Git, and the local branch in your local Git. The branch on Jira Git and the branch in your local Git will typically have the same name, let's say `branchname`; the remote-tracking branch in your local Git will typically have that name preceded by the origin name, let's say `origin/branchname`.

So, roughly speaking, the purpose of the remote-tracking branch is to act as a bridge between the other two:

- When you say `git fetch`, you sync Jira's Git's branches down to your local remote-tracking branches. Therefore you don't usually need to tell Git how to tie a remote-tracking branch to the Jira Git; it already knows how to do that, because it was set up for you that way when you said `git fetch`.
- When you say `git checkout` with a branch name that happens to match the name of a remote-tracking branch, Git assumes that what you really mean is, "Make a local branch and tie it to the remote-tracking branch of the same name." So it does that. That is why fetch and then checkout would have been the right thing to do originally. Instead, you made a local branch *manually*, and so it had no relation to the remote-tracking branch.
- When you say `git pull`, you sync a Jira Git branch down through to the local remote-tracking branch to the corresponding local branch. The first step, involving the remote-tracking branch, just makes a copy; but the second step *merges* (by default) the remote-tracking branch into the local branch.
- When you say `git push`, you sync the other way: the local branch is merged into the remote-tracking branch, which is then merged up into the corresponding Jira Git branch. Those merges are guaranteed to be fast-forward merges, because if they were not, Git would resist; you can overcome that resistance by using "force". If you say `git push` when the local branch is not tied to a remote tracking branch, you can tie it by adding the `-u` attribute: `git push -u origin branchname` is a common way to do a *first* push for a branch that you created locally, and after that you don't need the `-u` for that branch because the association has been made.

I have greatly simplified, but hopefully that's enough to give you a more accurate mental picture of what generally goes on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I went out of the branch I created on my git and did a ```git fetch``` and then checked in to the branch. And I'm hoping this time I checked out the remote branch as a local branch unless I checked back into the same branch that I had created previously but I'm still getting the same message.

Comment: Because you didn't check out the remote branch. You have a local branch and a remote branch, by the same name, but you still have not established any relationship between them. You could do that by saying `git branch -u origin/branchname branchname` if `origin` is the name of the remote.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be a long standing a bug in GIT.

This happens when you create a local branch and push it to a remote, so the tracking works. You can pull and push to and from it many times without problems, but if someone else pushes to the branch from a different clone, and then you pull, git looses the tracking information that was once working on your local copy.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/branch-name
```

fixes it, but there is no sane reason why someone else pushing to a remote should break your local copies tracking information.